# Why using offset for a Gamma (link=log) glm doesn't yield the same predicted average response as the average observed?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, offset

One of my analyst asked me why his Gamma/link=log glm with offsets was always overstating his observed data points.

I was able to reproduce the behavior in R with intercept only `glm` using offsets. For some reason, when you use offsets with a Gamma/link=log your predictions are overstated.

See this code :

```
set.seed(12345)
x <- rep(1,5)

#Gaussian
offs <- runif(5, 0, 1)
y <- runif(5, -5, 5) + offs
model1 <- glm(y ~ 1 + offset(offs), family=gaussian)
model2 <- glm(y - offs ~ 1, family=gaussian)
(cbind(mean(y), mean(predict(model1, type="response")), 
   mean(predict(model2, type="response") + offs)))

##            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
## [1,] 0.03836621 0.03836621 0.03836621

#Gamma
offs <- runif(5, 50, 150)
y <- runif(5, 1, 100) + offs
model1 <- glm(y ~ 1 + offset(1/offs), family=Gamma)
model2 <- glm(y - offs ~ 1, family=Gamma)
(cbind(mean(y), mean(predict(model1, type="response")), 
        mean(predict(model2, type="response") + offs)))

##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
## [1,] 136.8067 136.8067 136.8067

#Poisson
offs <- rpois(5, 5)
y <- rpois(5, 1) + offs
model1 <- glm(y ~ 1 + offset(log(offs)), family=poisson)
model2 <- glm(y - offs ~ 1, family=poisson)
(cbind(mean(y), mean(predict(model1, type="response")), 
       mean(predict(model2,t ype="response") + offs)))

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  7.2  7.2  7.2

#Gamma-log - Offset same on each observation
offs <- rep(runif(1, 50, 150), 5)
y <- runif(5, 1, 100) + offs
model1 <- glm(y ~ 1  + offset(log(offs)), 
              family=Gamma(link="log"))
model2 <- glm(y - offs ~ 1, family=Gamma(link="log"))
(cbind(mean(y), mean(predict(model1, type="response")), 
      mean(predict(model2, type="response") + offs)))

##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
## [1,] 129.2581 129.2581 129.2581

#Gamma-log - Offset different per observation
offs <- runif(5, 50, 150)
y <- runif(5, 1, 100) + offs
model1 <- glm(y ~ 1 + offset(log(offs)), 
             family=Gamma(link="log"))
model2 <- glm(y - offs ~ 1, 
            family=Gamma(link="log"))
(cbind(mean(y), mean(predict(model1, type="response")), 
     mean(predict(model2, type="response") + offs))) 

##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
## [1,] 160.1253 164.3708 160.1253
```

Why am I getting a different value in the last chunk on [,2]. From the definition of the `glm` formula, it should be the same, no?

I’ve debugged the `glm.fit` function and the code works fine, its not returning the expected result or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model 1 and 2 are not the same model. The poisson GLM uses a log link. If you supply an `offset` the subtraction is taken from the linear predictor, i.e. the log-transformed response $\log(y)$. As you know $\log(a-b) \ne \log(a)-\log(b)$.